# MediaCodec flush() pixelation (Decoding from different sources)

Tags: android, h.264, video-encoding, decoding, android-mediacodec

When loading the decoder buffer from a second MediaExtractor source during the decoding process, a very fast pixelation transition between the two video sources is noticeable and trying to flush the decoder before swapping the video sources make the pixelation even longer and more noticeable. Does anyone know how to create a clean transition using MediaCodec API.

Comment: Are you decoding two streams with a single MediaCodec decoder?  (If so, don't -- you need to use two decoders, one for each stream.)

Comment: yes i'm decoding several streams with one decoder, is there a specific reason for not doing it? The reason I'm using one decoder is that I want to implement cross-fading effect between stream transitions and other effects

Comment: I notice the pixelation happens when I start feeding in the second stream from a non-sync frame (non I-frame). I want to be able to cut and edit from not necessarily an I-frame. Since I'm using decoding to surface and encoding from surface, in my test I was using the MediaExtractor to parse through the source frames before passing them to the decoder

Comment: The B and P frames in an MPEG stream are written in terms of the data previous sent.  If you switch from one stream to another, the assumptions made when the data was encoded are wrong.  Everything "resets" when an I frame is sent, so it's not unexpected for that to work, but in general you want to feed separate streams into separate decoders.  I don't know what the maximum number of simultaneous decoders is, but I think it's safe to assume that you can have two.

Comment: let's assume we can have two simultaneous decoders. would you please give me some clue on how to create cross-fading on the surface when the separate decoders decode to the same surface. How can I sync the availability of the decoders output buffer to create the fading with the timing that i want.

Comment: You should write that up as a new stackoverflow question.  Be sure to detail the fading effect you're trying to achieve and the timing you want.  (I'm guessing you'll decode to a pair of SurfaceTextures and use GLES to blend the images, but I'm not clear on what you're after.)